# Argument 1 passed to Coinbase\Wallet\Exception\HttpException::exceptionClass() must be an instance of Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface, null given

Tags: laravel, coinbase-api

When i run the Coin Base Transactions offline it works, but when i put it online it fails.
Here is my code for the transaction.

---

```
    $configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
    $client = Client::create($configuration);

    $account = $client->getPrimaryAccount();

    $address = new Address([
        'name' => 'New Address19'
    ]);

    $add = $client->createAccountAddress($account, $address);
    $addressId = $client->getAccountAddresses($account);
    $addresses = $client->getAccountAddress($account, $addressId->getFirstId());
    echo "Your address is: ".json_encode($addresses->getAddress())."<br>";
```

---

ive googled but all in vain, the answers i get from here of updatind the certificate in the etc folder also not working. Someone help me

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had teh same problem. The solution for was to download the cacert.pem file from:

https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html

Copy it to the Coinbase API `etc` folder (same place where you will find `ca-coinbase.crt`).

Then edit `src\COnfiguration.php` to refer to this new file:

```
    public function __construct(Authentication $authentication)
    {
        $this->authentication = $authentication;
        $this->apiUrl = self::DEFAULT_API_URL;
        $this->apiVersion = self::DEFAULT_API_VERSION;
//      $this->caBundle = __DIR__.'/../etc/ca-coinbase.crt'; // Replaced with:
        $this->caBundle = __DIR__.'/../etc/cacert.pem';
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

$configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
$client = Client::create($configuration);

```
$account = $client->getPrimaryAccount();

$address = new Address([
    'name' => 'New Address19'
]);

$add = $client->createAccountAddress($account, $address);
$addressId = $client->getAccountAddresses($account);
$addresses = $client->getAccountAddress($account, $addressId->getFirstId());
echo "Your address is: ".json_encode($addresses->getAddress())."<br>";
```

Comment: this doesnot work, its no different from what i posted. seems you did copy and paste