# Coinbase API cURL request results in CAPTCHA

Tags: api, php-curl, coinbase-api

I'm using cURL to hit the api.coinbase.com API endpoint and the results come back with a CAPTCHA requirement from Cloudflare.

Seems kind of odd to have a CAPTCHA on an endpoint written for scripts/servers to use instead of humans.

How can I hit the API with a script if it keeps requiring me to prove that I'm a human all the time?

Comment: Please did you find a solution to this? Facing a similar issue.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70341992/coinbase-api-returns-cloudflare-captcha-check-and-fails-to-execute

Answer (score 1):

... or just download the "official" library (https://developpaper.com/how-to-use-bitcoin-coinbase-wallet-library-to-develop-and-apply-php/)

... and then fix the cert issue that causes it to crash ([Argument 1 passed to Coinbase\Wallet\Exception\HttpException::exceptionClass() must be an instance of Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface, null given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64426851/argument-1-passed-to-coinbase-wallet-exception-httpexceptionexceptionclass-m))

That works, too.

Comment: Kindly elaborate on this. I'm facing the same issue. What exactly is the solution to this? @Highdel

Comment: Although that process worked, I eventually wound up making the cURL calls on my own from scratch. Their setup process is ridiculously messed up because there are so many versions (Coinbase, Coinbase Pro, GDAX, Exchange, etc.) and their documentation isn't explicit. 

However, I found that creating the API key through Coinbase Pro and making the API calls to the address api.exchange.coinbase.com works perfectly, so I skipped all the library stuff and just wrote the functions myself.

You would think that Coinbase Pro's API would be api.pro.coinbase.com... you'd be wrong.